# to remove item from custom adapter extends base adapter

Tags: android, listview

I wants to create a function in Custom Adapter which can remove item from the list , And then wants to implement the Custom Adapter class in the Main_Activity
and perform operations .

**My CustomAdapterClass**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String[] result;
Context context;
int[] imageId;
TextView tv;
ImageView img;

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList,
        int[] prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result = prgmNameList;
    context = mainActivity;
    imageId = prgmImages;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}


@SuppressLint({ "ViewHolder", "InflateParams" })
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    // holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    return rowView;
}

public void remove(Object item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

And MainActivityClass

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
CustomAdapter mAdapter;
ListView listView;
Context context;
TextView Tv;
// ArrayList<String> prgmName;
public static int[] prgmImages = { R.drawable.p1, R.drawable.p2,
        R.drawable.p3, R.drawable.p4 };

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);

    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, null, prgmImages);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] items = new String[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i] = "Item " + (i + 1);
    }
    context = MainActivity.this;
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Create a ListView-specific touch listener. ListViews are given
    // special treatment because
    // by default they handle touches for their list items... i.e. they're
    // in charge of drawing
    // the pressed state (the list selector), handling list item clicks,
    // etc.
    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
            listView,
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(ListView listView,
                        int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                        mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
    listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    // Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during
    // ListView scrolling,
    // we don't look for swipes.
    listView.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());

    // Set up normal ViewGroup example
    final ViewGroup dismissableContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.dismissable_container);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        final Button dismissableButton = new Button(this);
        dismissableButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        dismissableButton.setText("Button " + (i + 1));
        dismissableButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Clicked " + ((Button) view).getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        // Create a generic swipe-to-dismiss touch listener.
        dismissableButton.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeDismissTouchListener(
                dismissableButton, null,
                new SwipeDismissTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean canDismiss(Object token) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(View view, Object token) {
                        dismissableContainer.removeView(dismissableButton);
                    }
                }));
        dismissableContainer.addView(dismissableButton);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Clicked " + getListAdapter().getItem(position).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

I am getting error at `mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));`
How can i resolve it

Comment: What kinds of error are you getting?Can you show us?

Comment: it is saying that you need to "create a method **remove** in customAdapter Class "  but i dont know how to create a method that will remove item from list in CustomAdapter Class

Comment: Instead of removing view from adapter in OnDissmiss() method , remove item from the list you are providing to the adapter &  set adapter again.

Comment: yes i have to because i'm removing the item from the swipe not by clicking it .

Comment: perform both of the things.. try removing view & item too.

Comment: how can you tell me , actually i'm storing the images in each item . Instead of string thats why i also can't use ArrayList directly.